# MySQL: Updating all rows setting a field to 0, but setting one row's field to 1

Tags: php, mysql

Is there an efficient way to update a selection of rows' field to 0, but set One of these rows to 1 based on an ID.

Basically, I have multiple objects in a database, and I want to toggle between which one is "inuse", so the query will set one of the rows (by id) to inuse=1 and the others to inuse=0.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `inuse` = (`id` = 23)
```

Comment: Do you think this is faster/more efficient than you're Artem?

Comment: I think it's pretty much the same, if not exactly the same.

Comment: BTW, in this case, it's a more elegant solution because it's shorter, but as soon as you need to do something more complicated than setting a boolean value, this solution is not going to work.

Comment: Aye, This does the job just great. I'm just toggling inuse so it wont get any more complicated.

Cheers Guys :)

Answer (score 12):

Sure

```
UPDATE table SET inuse=IF(id=ABCD, 1, 0)
```

would set the inuse field to 1 if id is ABCD and 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE  table
SET     inuse = (id = @id)
WHERE   id = @id
        OR inuse
```

This will update only relevant rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE myTable
SET Field = 0
WHERE FieldID <> [WhateverID]

UPDATE myTable 
SET Field = 1
WHERE FieldId = [WhateverID]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
update tbl set inuse = if(test, 1, 0);
```

or shorter

```
update tbl set inuse = test;
```

for example

```
update tbl set inuse = name = 'foo';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are after to set a flag, so no other part of the code uses the same object at the same time, it's better if the calling code sets inuse=1 and resets it when done. Otherwise you will end up one thread to mark an object (row) as inuse, and then if another thread needs another object, it will reset the first one, while still in use.

If this is not the case, and you just want be able to set inuse for one, and reset all others, you can use:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET InUse = CASE
   WHEN myTable.id = @id THEN 1
   ELSE 0
END
```

Answer (score 0):

if your database uses transactions, this is the best way to do it:

```
update myTable set inuse = 0;
update myTable set inuse = 1 where id = ?;
```

if you are not using transactions, then the other answer using CASE is the best option since it's portable. but it will require more CPU time than the two UPDATE statements.