# MySQL UPDATE - SET field in column to 1, all other fields to 0, with one query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, where-clause

I am updating a field in a mysql column namend "frontpage", set it from 0 to 1.

No problem with this query:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET frontpage='1' WHERE user_id='999' AND poll_id='555'");
```

What I'd like to accomplish is, in case `user_id 999` got already other existing `poll_id`'s set to `1` in the past, these rows should be set to 0 automatically.

As a beginner learning MySQL, I would run 2 queries, first one to set everything to `frontpage='0' WHERE user_id='999'` and the second query to set `frontpage='1' WHERE user_id='999' AND poll_id='555'`.

My question now is, could this be done by using only one query, and how?

PS: Not sure if it has something to do with my question, I've read these answers [MySQL: Updating all rows setting a field to 0, but setting one row's field to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013042/mysql-updating-all-rows-setting-a-field-to-0-but-setting-one-rows-field-to-1) but I haven't really understood the logic, perhaps someone can explain it to a mysql beginner please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this logic:

```
UPDATE table
    SET frontpage = (case when poll_id = '555' then '1' else '0' end)
    WHERE user_id = '999';
```

As a note:  if the constants should really be integers, then drop the single quotes.  In fact, you can then simplify the query to:

```
UPDATE table
    SET frontpage = (poll_id = 555)
    WHERE user_id = 999;
```